# Deployment error for picklist values

Tags: apex, deployment, picklist

In phy.object file i have included below things.

```
<recordTypes>
        <fullName>Physician</fullName>
        <active>true</active>
        <label>Physician</label>
        <picklistValues>
            <picklist>Country__c</picklist>
            <values>
                <fullName>US</fullName>
                <default>true</default>
            </values>
        </picklistValues>
```

i am getting below error

Picklist value: US in picklist: Country__c not found

of Type recordtype.Physician is a recordtype.

Comment: <recordTypes>
        <fullName>Physician</fullName>
        <active>true</active>
        <label>Physician</label>
        <picklistValues>
            <picklist>Country__c
            <values>
                <fullName>US</fullName>
                <default>true</default>
            </values>
</picklist>
        </picklistValues>

Comment: Check if this works

Comment: @tejas-Your xml looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you have added the picklist value "US" to your record type "Physician" under the field country__c in the source org